# Увеличение диапазона цветов в консоли

Tags: c++

В колледже начали курсовую по разработке приложения на плюсах, ну я с языком поработал - мне понравилось и я решил написать игрушку в консоли **[пояснение к тому - зачем я вообще этим занимаюсь]**, вопрос заключается в следующем: по стандарту консоль обладает всего 16'ю цветами, но я видел что можно использовать гораздо больше. Как можно увеличить этот диапазон цветов при помощи C++?

Comment: вы видели именно в консоли? или в приложении, которое создает свою консоль, а не использует стандартную?

Comment: Честно говоря не уверен - к примеру dwarf fortress и тайлы которые к нему можно установить, эта игра чисто консольная насколько я знаю. В чем различие между второй и первой консолями, вторая что то вроде имитации?

Comment: См. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors. Поддержка зависит от эмулятора терминала.

Comment: Тут тоже много интересного https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728

Comment: Судя по тому, что конкретная платформа нигде не указана, для вас существует только Та Самая. Обозначьте её как-нибудь, пожалуйста: меткой или в тексте вопроса.